# How do you restore the special folder icons in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

Problem:

The desktop and documents folder appear with normal icons.

Attempted Solutions:

- Restoring desktop.ini
- Clearing the icon cache
- Rebooting
- Restoring the documents icon to default (via Control Panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could mark one of the answers as "accepted" but reality proved to be even stranger.

Shortly after I asked this question, my laptop was stolen. Consequently, in the interest of increasing my acceptance rate, my 'official accepted answer' is:

Buy a new laptop.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Check this page out: "[Shell folders are displayed with the standard folder icon in Windows Vista](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/130/1/Shell-folders-are-displayed-with-the-standard-folder-icon-in-Windows-Vista.html)" - it sounds like what you're running into.

Blurb from page:

> Symptom:
>
> When you open Windows
> Explorer, the shell folders such as
> Documents and Pictures may be
> displayed with a standard folder icon
> rather than the special folder icons.
>
> Resolution:
>
> This behavior can occur
> when the desktop.ini file in the shell
> folder is missing or incorrect, or it
> has no attributes set. The default
> contents of the desktop.ini file for
> various shell folders in Windows Vista
> are given below. In each shell folder
> that's missing the special icon,
> create a file named desktop.ini and
> paste the content corresponding to the
> shell folder.

It then goes on to give you code for the Shell folders' specific desktop.ini settings.

```
Documents
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235

Desktop
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-183
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to assign the read-only attribute to the folder.

eg.
`attrib +r %userprofile%\Desktop`

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to restore your shell folder default icon in Vista - you may want to backup your information first:

1. Go to the folder you want to restore. For example, main music or picture folder.
2. Hightlight the folder.
3. Single right click
4. Click *properties*.
5. Click *customize*.
6. Click *choose file*.
7. Go to *organize* and click.
8. Repeat steps 4 and 5.
9. In *folder icons* click Change Icon.
10. Click *restore default* and click OK if you have to, then close all open windows.
11. Restart your computer. (*I didn't restart, I just reopened my main user folder and refreshed the window about 3 times*)